# Wordpress updates

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp

When I am updating plugins / versions / themes, how do I know whether wordpress is using FTP or SFTP or SSH to update them? Is there a way I can check it through Wordpress? Thankss! Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wireshark to see what's going on inside your network adapter, including the protocol that is be used by the current connection.